# CoreData: saving data to context

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am working on to use CoreData to save data of an object to an entity created in the datamodeld file.

In my scenario, I made a datamodeld called Product which represents an item available in the grocery store.

I have several categories for each type of products. For example, produce, dairy, meat, etc... If I save those products in the Product context, they will all be aggregated into one database and retrieving the data will be a hassle.

I'm wondering if it is possible to store my items into different databases of the Product context.

The only workaround I can think of is to create an entity for each categories which is a child of Product. I don't like this workaround because I am creating unnecessarily entities (every products in each categories have the same attributes).

Answer (score 0):

By "product context", I guess you mean managedObjextContext? Your data is not saved in moc, you write data on moc and it's reflected persistent store.

You can use multiple moc to save the data of your app but be extra careful to syncronize the moc to moc on main thread.

I did something on the same lines that you are proposing as a work around. It worked out fine in my case.